# How to increase the width of tables to fit the popup if they are side bye side?

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to increase the size of my side-to-side tables to fit the whole page but it does not work I added the `style="width: 50%"`  to each table but it shows the first table in a row and the second table in other row and I want them to be horizontally sided and fitting the whole page

```
<table style="float: left">
   <thead>
       <tr>
            <th>A</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
            <td>100</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<table style="float: left">
   <thead>
       <tr>
            <th>B</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
            <td>200</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding the display: flex; in the parent element.

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>100</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>B</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To put both tables in the cells of the other table.
   Or
2. To combinate style width - maybe 45% + 45 % etc.
   Or
3. Set table width in pixels but not in percents. In that way your site will not be adaptive for all devices and monitors.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. In my opinion, the best two ways are the following:

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <table style="flex-grow: 1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>100</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table style="flex-grow: 1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>B</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>200</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Or:

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>100</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>B</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>200</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

With either of these examples, if you would like to add some spacing between these two tables, you can use the CSS `gap` property on the div like so: `gap: 1 rem`